# ClassCastException occured on Solver.solve

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

i was tinkering a bit with optaplanner-webexamples vrp.
so i kind of using spring-boot for it, and i edit a few bit of model etc.

but when running solve it produce ClassCastException on VehicleRoutingSolution class

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: id.co.asyst.vrp.core.solution.VehicleRoutingSolution cannot be cast to id.co.asyst.vrp.core.solution.VehicleRoutingSolution
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.LambdaBeanPropertyMemberAccessor.executeGetter(LambdaBeanPropertyMemberAccessor.java:120)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.getScore(SolutionDescriptor.java:1071)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.cloneSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:212)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.setWorkingSolutionFromBestSolution(DefaultSolverScope.java:230)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:75)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:210)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:190)
at id.co.asyst.vrp.rest.cdi.VehicleRoutingSolverManager.lambda$solve$1(VehicleRoutingSolverManager.java:105)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

where did i do wrong?
most of the code i took directly from optaplanner-webexamples with few modifications to model. mostly just table relationship.

thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: this seems odd. do you have dependencies on different version(s) of the library this class is in?

Comment: These strange class cast execeptions often occur when those two classes are loaded by different class loaders.

Comment: Yes. Probably copy pasted the example code (good) and added `optaplanner-examples` to the dependencies (bad).

Comment: the old code doesn't have `optaplanner-examples` in it's dependencies though.
the new one i use to test and copy as vanilla did though. haven't tested further yet

Comment: after tinkering around, turns out it was because of `spring-boot-devtools`
after i remove `spring-boot-devtools` from dependencies it runs normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's because of spring-boot-devtools. after i removed it from `pom.xml` it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've come up with is to use the context classloader as recommended in [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload). Use the context classloader as the second argument to `SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource()`. For example:

```java
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
SolverFactory<VehicleRoutingSolution> sf = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(
        "org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml",
        classLoader
);
```

As in my previous answer, this works together with Developer Tools, so you can leave `spring-boot-devtools` in your POM and keep using the [Automatic Restart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart) feature.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46401979/1682984) for further details. You have to check where the duplicate occurrence is:

```
System.out.println(TheGhostClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that doesn't require giving up on `spring-boot-devtools` is to "promote" `optaplanner-core` JAR to the "restart" classloader that's part of `spring-boot-devtools`. This can be achieved by creating `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-devtools.properties` with the following content:

```
restart.include.optaplanner=/optaplanner-core.*jar
```

More info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload.